# The difference between initializing a variable with new() or default?

Tags: c#, .net

Code:

```
using System;

int first = 0;
int second = new();
int third = default;

Console.WriteLine("first: {0};", first);
Console.WriteLine("second: {0};", second);
Console.WriteLine("third: {0};", third);
```

What is the difference between `new()`, `default` and `0` in this context?

Comment: I doubt an int can be initialized with new()

Comment: But it works. [link](https://imgur.com/a/OhLe6NT)!
p.s. Sorry about the Russian interface

Comment: @RandRandom - It's perfectly fine to do `int second = new();`.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Never seen it before so I doubted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For primitive value types (such as integer) the compiler emits identical code
for all three cases

```cs
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 first,
        [1] int32 second,
        [2] int32 third
   )

// int value = 0;
IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
IL_0001: stloc.0
// int value2 = 0;
IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
IL_0003: stloc.1
// int value3 = 0;
IL_0004: ldc.i4.0
IL_0005: stloc.2
```

The major difference between default() and new() is for reference types.
defaut() is identical to assigning to null, whereas new() calls a constructor

Answer (score 4):

You're absolutely right that the value of your three variables is identical when you run this code:

```
int first = 0;
int second = new();
int third = default;

Console.WriteLine("first: {0};", first);
Console.WriteLine("second: {0};", second);
Console.WriteLine("third: {0};", third);
```

I get this output:

```
first: 0;
second: 0;
third: 0;
```

But let's change that to objects.

```
object first = 0;
object second = new();
object third = default;
```

No I get this:

```
first: 0;
second: System.Object;
third: ;
```

The `first` is `0`, the `second` an instance of a object, and the `third` is `null`.

Three different values.

The reason behind this is for generics. Let's say I have this method:

```
public T GiveMeTheDefault<T>() => default(T);
```

Here the compiler will return a `new()` for a value type and a `null` for a reference type.